# How to do checkIn major version through REST Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, rest

Im tryin to do checkin major version through REST API.

This url is working just fine and I can do minor version checked in

```
/sites/developersite/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Document')/Files/GetByUrl('file.docx')/CheckIn('Comment')
```

but I cant get this one working

```
/sites/developersite/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Document')/Files/GetByUrl('file.docx')/CheckIn('Comment', 1)
```

Argument 1 suppose to be major version checkin type.

Documentation on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj247012.aspx)  says that second url should be working.

Error that Im getting when second url is used

```
{
"error":{
   "code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException",
   "message":{
      "lang":"en-US",
      "value":"The expression \"web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Documents')/Files/GetByUrl('file.docx')/CheckIn('Comment',1)\" is not valid."
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: `CheckInType` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee553393%28v=office.14%29.aspx says you are correct with your `1`. Weird.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't done that with REST before, but in this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn198245.aspx) he uses this syntax:

```
http://<site url>/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(
  '/Shared Documents/a.txt')/CheckOut()
http://<site url>/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(
  '/Shared Documents/a.txt')/CheckIn(comment='Comment', checkintype=0)
```