# MS Flow Approval from SharePoint failing

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, ms-flow

I have a MS Flow Approval process which is triggered via a selected file in SharePoint.
The flow should be:

- User Selects file and triggers flow
- Flow Approval process starts which emails manager for approval
- List item is published if approval process accepted

The problem is it seems to fail if the manager doesnt approve instantly. See flow:
[image: MS Flow]

My assumption is the sharepoint token is expiring, but is there a work around? its happening within 48hours.

update: I read somewhere that I need to do a Get metadata after the approval process to refresh the etag, I did this, with the same error, screen shot below:

[image]

Comment: Hi, can you add screenshot of the 'Set Content Approval Status'? Thank you

Comment: Ive added it along with the update

Comment: Under which account you are publishing this flow?

Comment: A user with Full control over the document library

Comment: Ok, so if somebody approve instantly it's working correctly?

Comment: have you tried to use "HTTP request to SharePoint" and use API to publish a document? examples here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/70316/how-to-do-checkin-major-version-through-rest-sharepoint-2013

Comment: Good idea, will try.

Comment: Try, if it will be ok, i will create from this an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is the file, or its metadata, being updated by someone (or another process) after initially being set to Pending, but before the manager approves?

If the document is updated in any way, **the document would automatically revert to draft mode**.  However, this won't stop your Flow.  When the manager eventually does try to approve, the Flow will fail because the document needs to be at Pending/Submit mode.  This could certainly explain why the Flow works if approved *immediately* (as nobody has had a chance to edit).

You can verify this by adding an additional "Set Content Approval Status" immediately before the final Approve action:

[image]